# How can we construct a set element using the set constructor example below?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, set

I have been studying the set container of c++ and I got confused by an example code that is provided at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/ as an example to utilize set constructors.

I understand that set has an input parameter called **comp** to determine how the ordering is done, however when I checked the declarations for the constructors of set at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/, I couldn't see a declaration that accepts two arguments as template parameters in the way we create a set element below. Would someone be kind enough to explain to me what type of set constructor is called here and how this specific constructor works?

```cpp
...

struct classcomp {
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
  {return lhs<rhs;}
};

int main ()
{
  ...

  std::set<int,classcomp> fifth;                 // class as Compare

  ...
}
```

Comment: Default parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can actually take three template parameters but the second and third are optional:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

The constructor you've used is called the [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) but that doesn't have anything to do with the template parameters used. It's the fact that you create the set without arguments to the constructor that makes it use the default constructor.

Comment: Oh I see, I was confused due to usage of template parameters. I understand that they specify the type and don't act as input parameters now. I guess, I will have to do some reading about the optional parameters. Thanks a lot!